# Store record of purchased items locally vs query google play for purchased items [ queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener)]

Tags: android, sqlite, android-billing

I am using IAB for my application.

Google's IAB v3 API provides a method to query Google Play for managed items already owned by the user(device) v.i.z. `queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener)`

However, I also use a SQLite database for my app , so I am thinking of storing the record of purchased items in my own database instead of querying google play every second time.

Is this a bad idea?

What are the pros and cons of  `queryInventoryAsync` vs storing purchased items in local SQLite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User can manually clear application data and your database will be dropped. Or user 
can run the application on another device with same account.

[Purchasing In-app Billing Products](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html)

> It is good practice to frequently query the In-app Billing service for
>   the user’s purchases, for example whenever the app starts up or
>   resumes, so that the user’s current in-app product ownership
>   information is always reflected in your app.

Comment: Anything apart from that?